# In R, what is the difference between unlink and file.remove?

Tags: r

R provides two functions to remove files (and folder) from the file system:

- `unlink`
- `file.remove`

It's not entirely obvious what the differences are, or indeed when to use which, other than that `unlink` takes some additional arguments.

Reading the source code for these functions doesn't help very much, since both simply calls a compiled C function.

What are the differences? When should you use `unlink` in preference to `file.remove`, or vice versa?

Comment: you can find the implementation here: http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/platform.c

Comment: `unlink` will delete directories, but `file.remove` will only delete empty ones, and not on Windows

Comment: FYI: In R news, changes in version 2.15.0: "The behaviour of unlink(recursive = TRUE) for a symbolic link to a directory has changed: it now removes the link rather than the directory contents (just as rm -r does)."

Answer (score 30, accepted):

My guess is simply that `unlink` was present in S, since it references Becker, Chambers and Wilks (1988), whereas `file.remove` (and file.copy, file.create, etc.) have been part of R since early on in order to provide a family of functions for general file manipulation.

`unlink` corresponds to a very old Unix function (and certainly existed when the 1988 version of S appeared): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unlink_(Unix)

So, `unlink` is there for compatibility with S, `file.remove` is there as a part of R and both are maintained in order to support long existing code from S and R. Other than that simply choose the one that suits your needs (or habits) best.

Answer (score 9):

The main practical difference in the behaviour of the functions is how they handle a file that is currently open, and thus which cannot be immediately deleted:

- `unlink()` marks the file for deletion as soon as it is not open in any other context;
- `file.remove()` leaves the file intact, returning `FALSE`, but throws a warning.

Related: [how to remove the file when "permisson denied" in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122968/22883226)

Comment: `unlink` allows "globbed" filenames, `file.remove()` seems not to.