# how to remove the file when "permisson denied" in R?

Tags: r, file

My system is "win7", and I want to delete the file "workspace".

```
file.remove("c:\\workspace")
# [1] FALSE
# Warning message:
# In file.remove("c:\\workspace") :
# cannot remove file 'c:\workspace', reason 'Permission denied'
```

How can I give the R the power to delete it?

```
file.info("c:\\workspace")
#               size isdir mode               mtime               ctime
# c:\\workspace    0  TRUE  777 2014-01-01 14:42:51 2014-01-01 14:33:27
#                             atime exe
# c:\\workspace 2014-02-25 09:39:08  no
```

Comment: I don't know R, but is that really a *directory*, not a file, and does that matter in R? Perhaps permission denied because it's a non-empty directory?

Comment: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-remove-directory-td3039459.html

Comment: When starting R (or RStudio or whatever you're using) try running it as an administrator.

Comment: Is the folder being used by another process?

Comment: I solved it in CMD ,`net user administrator /active:yes` and delete it with `move ` command

Comment: @BrodieG: I would disagree. `?file.remove` says: "'file.remove' attempts to remove the files named in its argument.  On most Unix platforms 'file' includes _empty_ directories, symbolic links, fifos and sockets.  On Windows, 'file' means a regular file and not, say, an empty directory." And the example section creates a temporary directory, copies files into it, removes those files, then deletes the directory (using `unlink`).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@TypeIA answered it in a comment, but I'll formalize it here: `help(unlink)`.

```
file.create('somefile')
# [1] TRUE
file.remove('somefile')
# [1] TRUE

dir.create('somedir')
file.remove('somedir')
# [1] FALSE
# Warning message:
# In file.remove("somedir") :
#   cannot remove file 'somedir', reason 'Permission denied'
unlink('somedir', recursive=TRUE)
```

(The directory is gone.)

Comment: In retrospect, it might be good to think of `unlink(..., recursive=TRUE)` along the lines of the unix line `rm -f ...`.